# Powershell: Get certain attributes from resultset

Tags: sql, powershell

In a rather small powershell script, I retrieve data from a sql database using invoke-sqlmd. The output is written into a variable. Later in the script, I want to use only one attribute of this result set in a foreach loop. How can I call on that specific attribute?
If the question was not well asked, please feel free to ask for further information.

This is the sqlcmd:

```
$SQLcmd = "Select * From (SELECT t.[Initiator] ,t.[EndTime] ,t.StartTime ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), t.StartTime, 111) as Datum ,t.[Result] as Result ,GDI.[Name] ,P.DisplayString ,Pi.DisplayString as DisplayStringDeutsch FROM [M42STORE].$SQL_Table t join [dbo].[GDIEImportClassBase] GDI on GDI.ID = t.ImportSequence left join [dbo].[GDIEImportPickupResult] P on P.Value = t.Result left join [dbo].[GDIEImportPickupResult-CI] Pi on Pi.Owner = P.ID and Pi.LCID = 7 ) Q WHERE Result = '3'"
```

Comment: could you please post the code and let us know what are the attributes you are trying to get out of the variable

Comment: sorry for bad formatting

Comment: what you need to do is after storing the result in a varaible lets say $result, just pipe it to select that property (column header in your case) like: $result | select GDI

Comment: `$name = $Import | select Name`

do you mean something like this? unfortunately this does not give me any result.

fyi.

`Initiator            : SYSTEM
EndTime              : 25.09.2016 03:00:06
StartTime            : 24.09.2016 21:00:20
Datum                : 2016/09/24
Result               : 3
Name                 : TURNUS_11.007_ICA_Update_processed_Ticket_data
DisplayString        : Failure
DisplayStringDeutsch : Fehler`

this is what one result from the $import variable looks like

Comment: no.. Have you got the result set inside the variable? Have you executed the query and stored the result in the variable ???

Comment: Yes I did, but I found another solution to my problem. In the foreach loop I could just go for `$item.Name` which is way easier imo. Thx anyway for your help

Comment: but why to iterate each time. Anyways, its your choice. if it helps. Could you please post it as answer and mark as accepted . So that this could be closed